# Android: findViewById(R.id.btn_mAmperClear).setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-intent

I have some problem with setOnClickListener in my simple Android Application.
My Situation:

I have main screen with 4 buttons 
button 1 (works)
button 2 (works)
button 2 (EEeeeee...rror)
button 4 (not connected yet)

I've connect 2 first buttons with new activities (all works great). 
Problems starts when I'm creating 3th button. I have code:

```
findViewById(R.id.btn_mAmperClear).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

        }
    });
```

With clear class file (java file without code above) all works great - I have no errors, after i will add upper code i have crash in my app :(

FATAL EXCEPTION:main
java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package.Name.ActivityName} java.lang.NullPointerException

3 other situations works great (that code above works).

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

The call to `findViewById(R.id.btn_mAmperClear)` is returning null. This means that you don't actually have a view with that ID in the layout.xml for the activity.

Either that or this is one of those "Eclipse didn't properly build my project because it is too stupid to know about the dependency chain and it didn't compile everything it was supposed to" errors. If that's the case, simply do a "clean" on your project and rebuild it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Do that in this manner..

```
private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;
private Button btn3;
private Button btn4;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourPage);

    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
    btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_3);
    btn4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_4);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btn_1:
                    //do your stuff
        break;
    case R.id.btn_2:
                    //do your stuff
        break;
    case R.id.btn_3:
                    //do your stuff
        break;
    case R.id.btn_4:
                    //do your stuff
        break;
     }
}
```